# How to use H tags correctly?

Tags: html, header, seo

I'm looking at my template now, and I see a problem. Although, I'm not too advanced, so here I am, asking if I'm seeing a problem when there isn't one:

Homepage contains:

15 H1 tags, one for each post header.

0 H2 tags.

3 H3 tags, for the widget titles.

8 H4 tags, for widget contents.

0 H5 tags.

0 H6 tags.

Same goes for a single page, except it contains 1 H1 tag.

So I'm seeing a problem because there is no H2 tags, there is H3 and H4 tags, and then no H5 and H6 tags.

Comment: Why do you care? It doesn't matter if H2-s are missing. It's just a heading tag, they are not mandatory.

Comment: SEO is important when you aren't very social, can't specialize in local public and can't pay for ads.

Comment: An H1 tag would be the main title for the content, and would be for a unique titl. I don't think there is a huge difference between h1 and h2 in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would for for your homepage :

- 1 H1 tags, title of the website.
- XX H2 tags, one for each post header.
- XX H2 tags, for the widget titles.
- XX H2 tags, for widget contents.

You have to use H3 for content directly related to the previous H2 in the page. The inferior title tags must used when a semantic relationship exists between, eg :

```
h1 : 10 cars I love
p : intro

h2 : Audi A5 (the first car)
p : some text about the audi

h3 : the speed of the A5
p : some text about the speed of the audi A5
h3 : another thing I love about the A5
p : text about this....

h2 : second car I love
same structure as the Audi A5 part
```

This way, you have a relationship between every title tags and the immediate following title level.

For your homepage, the different titles seems totally unrelated, thus you should use H2 only for them.

Comment: That is interesting, do search engines (Google?) pick up on these things? I actually thought that Google takes all `<H1>` tags, the more there are, the less significant they are, then does the same for `<H2>` and makes it's way to `<H6>`. But if it does pick up on nested lists, what about the widgets then? Should I use `<H4>` to `<H6>` for them, and listing contents inside them? They have links to my posts, for example "Most Popular Posts" containing five links, etc..

Comment: Google doest use it somehow, but best practice today is to have **only one** H1 on the page (this is the headline of the page). Multiple H1 confuse search engines. There is no such thing as significant Hx or not.

For your widget, you should not use Hx everywhere, only use H4-6 when you have a very long page. Use H2 for the title of the widget (Most Popular Posts) and use simple <a> for the links.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one h1 per HTML document.

But h2, h3, h4, h5 you can use at will.

But following a hierarchy. So, try to not skip a level.

Comment: Here you can read more details about this topic. http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/

Comment: Here is another good reference: http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/multiple-h1-tags/

Comment: You can absolutely have multiple `<h1>` tags per HTML document.

Comment: But is not recommended for SEO. He can also use only <span> if a correctly use of headers is not a thread.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann As far, as I know, H2-6 tags do not degrade SEO importance of H1 tags, and extra titles can't be bad? So why use span tags?

Comment: There is no why to use only span ontags, its dumb. Anyway, the <h1> element is THE most important group of words that better represent the content of the HTML document. Sure, you can use how many <h1> tags you want, but its not recommended. Dont worry too much with the other headings. But make sure that have only one <h1>, if you need to repeat a <h1>, like a list of blog posts, so at this level it must be a <h2> and the <h1> must be something like "Post List" and the <h2> the post titles.

Comment: What about the homepage, what should I use as a H1 element in there?

Comment: You can write "Home Page" or some clue of a important content there is there.

Comment: Yea, but I don't have a place to put that text.